# Can an OpenPGP public key without UID exist?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, oracle-fusion-middleware

Is below key valid?

The `gpg --list-keys` command lists the key information which has no label/email to it, I mean UID:

```
/home/XXXXXX/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
--------------------------------
pub   2048R/3BAAF156 2016-04-05
uid
```

Is it a valid key? Source said they are using Oracle Fusion Middleware pgp to generate the key.

How can I encrypt files using the key which has no UID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RFC 4880, OpenPGP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) does not require keys to have a UID attached. Anyway, the output you posted seems more like the key has an *empty* UID (which is not forbidden when reading [section 5.11.  User ID Packet (Tag 13)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.11)). You can have GnuPG list all individual OpenPGP packets the key is constructed from by running `gpg --export 3BAAF156 | gpg --list-packets`.

There are more ways to address a key than the UID -- actually, especially for scripting and development purposes specifying a fixed key ID or even better fingerprint is preferred. The short key ID that you can use is `3BAAF156` (instead of a mail address), but [better use long key IDs instead](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/84280/19837).

An example for the short key ID, encrypting the file `example.txt`:

```
gpg --recipient 3BAAF156 --encrypt example.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I say it's unusal (if not invalid) to have an empty UID. E.g., GPG 2.1.11 does not allow me to generate a key with an empty UID:

```
export GNUPGHOME=$(mktemp -d) # use temporary dir; unset when done
gpg --batch --passphrase 'pass' --quick-gen-key ''
```

I get:

```
gpg: Key generation failed: Invalid user ID
```

Furthermore, `gpg --edit-key` does not allow me to delete the last `uid`.

To answer your second question, you can (try to) use that key using its "key id", `3BAAF156` in your case:

```
echo hello | gpg --encrypt --armor --recipient 3BAAF156
```